# How would you write this condition in a cleaner way?

Tags: python

I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way to write this condition:

```
if area.spaces[0].shading.type == 'MATERIAL' and not area.spaces[0].shading.use_scene_world:
       intensity = intensity
   else:
       intensity /= pow(2, (context.scene.view_settings.exposure))
```

I couldn't find a way to get the inverted intersection I want to get rid of the else.

Comment: Is intensity  used when the shading type is not MATERIAL?

Comment: Intensity division should happen when it's not MATERIAL, and when it's not use_scene_world when it is MATERIAL.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while it *does* use the Blender Python API, it is a general programming question unrelated to Blender. (I would also vote to close this as an opinion based question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also improve readability by reducing the maximum line length.

```
shading = area.spaces[0].shading
if (shading.type != 'MATERIAL' or shading.use_scene_world):
    intensity /= pow(2, (context.scene.view_settings.exposure))
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I don't think the "or" will give the same intersection though?

Comment: Follows De Morgan's Law "not (A and B) == not A or not B"

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like learning things :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually suggest making a human readable temporary variables.

They will immediately show everyone who's reading the code what they mean just like comments.

```
isShadingTypeMaterial = (area.spaces[0].shading.type == 'MATERIAL')
isShadingUseSceneWorld = (area.spaces[0].shading.use_scene_world)

if isShadingTypeMaterial and not isShadingUseSceneWorld:
    intensity = intensity
else:
    intensity /= pow(2, (context.scene.view_settings.exposure))
```

Comment: `is_shading_type_material` would make it even more readable according to pep8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names